# Avoiding drag and drop from embedded Web Browser

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc

I have written a Win32 sample, in this sample I have added web Browser control. It is working fine.

I launch the application with web page having some images. Here I can drag the images on to the desktop.

One of the requirements says that application should not allow drag and drop feature.

Please let me know how to disable this feature.

Comment: If this requirement is for security, what prevents a user from just doing a print-screen and pasting the picture into a photo editor? Otherwise, why is this requirement important?

Comment: for the requirement user is not allowed to get any images or print the page from the web page. he can only view the images.

Comment: Everything that is shown on the screen can be copied and printed!